# Retrieving record parameters from TProgramInfo in DWScript

Tags: delphi, dwscript

How do you retrieve record parameters from a TProgramInfo object in the Eval events for functions in a TdwsUnit? It seems that the object only provides ways to retrieve the basic datatypes directly or possibly a script object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Members[]` property to access record members, for instance if you have a script variable `p` of type `TPoint`, you can access and set the X/Y members with

```
var p : IInfo;
...
p:=Info.Vars['p'];

px := p.Member['x'].Value;
py := p.Member['y'].Value;
```

(cf. PredefinedRecord in TdwsUnitTests)

Comment: The function parameters are also included in these variables?

Comment: Yes, functions parameters are seen as variable, as are Result & Self (when applicable). You've got shortcut methods & properties for Result & Self, but you don't have to use them.